# "Heap corruption detected" when I splice together strings in JNI

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I used JNI to concatenate strings like this, and received an APP crash error: "heap corruption detected by dlmalloc_real", the compiler told me that there was a problem with the memory heap. I am a newbie, and I don’t know if I use JNI to concatenate correctly. I other will receive this error when +1 or not +1 when allocating a memory block of char. This error directly caused my APP to crash, and there was no error log can track. I only received one: ‘ heap corruption detected by dlmalloc_real’. This error currently only appears on Android 5.x. No other versions have found this error. So I want to know if my JNI to concatenate strings of stitching is wrong.

this is my code [original screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcvNv.jpg), the `re` value is returned directly to the JAVA layer at the end.

```
    const char *username = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, user_name, NULL);
    const char *password = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, pass_word, NULL);
    const char *http = "thi is a string***";
    const char *pas = "*thi is a string****";
    const char *httpTail = "thi is a string***";
    char *host = (char *) malloc(
            strlen(http) + strlen(username) +strlen(pas) + strlen(password) + strlen(httpTail)+1);
    strcat(host, http);
    strcat(host, username);
    strcat(host, pas);
    strcat(host, password);
    strcat(host, httpTail);
    correctUtfBytes(host);
    (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, user_name, username);
    (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, pass_word, password);
    jstring re = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, host);
    return re;
```

This method only checks whether the encoding conforms to C's encoding format. If no detection and conversion is made, the function newstringutf may report an error that the encoding format does not conform, because Java's string and C's char character encoding are different

```
void correctUtfBytes(char *bytes) {
    char three = 0;
    while (*bytes != '\0') {
        unsigned char utf8 = *(bytes++);
        three = 0;
        // Switch on the high four bits.
        switch (utf8 >> 4) {
            case 0x00:
            case 0x01:
            case 0x02:
            case 0x03:
            case 0x04:
            case 0x05:
            case 0x06:
            case 0x07:
                // Bit pattern 0xxx. No need for any extra bytes.
                break;
            case 0x08:
            case 0x09:
            case 0x0a:
            case 0x0b:
            case 0x0f:
                /*
                 * Bit pattern 10xx or 1111, which are illegal start bytes.
                 * Note: 1111 is valid for normal UTF-8, but not the
                 * modified UTF-8 used here.
                 */
                *(bytes - 1) = '?';
                break;
            case 0x0e:
                // Bit pattern 1110, so there are two additional bytes.
                utf8 = *(bytes++);
                if ((utf8 & 0xc0) != 0x80) {
                    --bytes;
                    *(bytes - 1) = '?';
                    break;
                }
                three = 1;
                // Fall through to take care of the final byte.
            case 0x0c:
            case 0x0d:
                // Bit pattern 110x, so there is one additional byte.
                utf8 = *(bytes++);
                if ((utf8 & 0xc0) != 0x80) {
                    --bytes;
                    if (three)--bytes;
                    *(bytes - 1) = '?';
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't post screenshots of code. Edit your question and add the code itself, as text.

Comment: I have re-edited the question

Comment: What does `correctUtfBytes` do?

Comment: OT: you can simplify this code as `char * host; asprintf(&host, "%s%s%s%s%s", http, username, pas, password, httpTail);` (and don't forget to call `free(host)` at the end!)

Comment: It looks like you are constructing a HTTP url. Did you already account for the necessary URL -encoding of `username` and `password`?

Comment: Because java's string character encoding is not the same as C's char encoding, correctutfbytes just checks the different encodings and converts them to C's char encoding to avoid newStringUTF. This function may crash due to character encoding

Comment: Yes, I should be constructing a http URL, username and password encoding should be fine. The crash happened after I had finished building the URL string. I printed the URL characters in the next step, and it was already returning the string URL. Then it crashed. It just reminds me that something is wrong with the memory heap
 
theT͟Hē,T͟Hə

Comment: You will need to show the implementation of `correctUtfBytes`.

Comment: I have re-edited the question ,Pasted the code for the correctutfbytes method

Comment: Why are you using JNI at all for this? One line of code in Java.

Comment: @ Botje I tried the writing you provided, but I still get an error saying that my memory heap is damaged ...

Comment: @user207421 I want to learn more. Just looking at the code in the book, I can only expand the knowledge. There are some problems that may arise in actual operation. So I like tossing and tossing, this can make me more knowledge and make me more powerful

Comment: Your correctUtfBytes looks harmless enough. Is it possible your problem is elsewhere? What other native code do you have?

Comment: @Botje A pubilc static native String (String uname, String pword) of the upper java, the connected JNI function returns Jstring, and the above code, there is no other, the Java connection JNI function is generated by the as compiler alt + enter of

Comment: @Botje  What other native code？Does it refer to other functional methods? some. There are several other functions written the same way

Comment: Somewhere you are writing past the edge of allocated memory, and the memory allocator is calling you out on it. If you can, inspect the pointed-to memory and the memory right before it, that might give some clues.

Comment: It shouldn't. I ran the automatic script for a day or two on other versions of Android, and it was very stable. There was no OOM and no memory leak. The above problem only appeared in the Android 5.0.2 version, and the manufacturer of the ROM of the 5.0.2 system device was customized. I only have a 5.0.2 device. No other 5.0.2 devices were tested. Perhaps the custom Rom manufacturer modified some rules to cause this problem. But I cannot verify. I feel very depressed